# SharePoint 2010 Loop that adds new viewfield to every Library view

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

This script is supposed to loop through each document library on each site and add viefield called “CheckoutUser” to the default view.
Problem is that the script adds the field only to the first library in each site, skips all other libraries and proceeds to the next site.

I need help with solving this problem, 
Thanks, Anna

```
$site = Get-SPSite "http://sharepoint"

$site | Get-SPWeb -limit all | ForEach-Object {

    $_.Lists |  where  {$_.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary"} | ForEach-Object { 

        $view = $_.DefaultView

        $view.ViewFields.add("CheckoutUser")

        $view.Update()
    }
}

$site.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$site = Get-SPSite "http://sharepoint"
$column = "CheckoutUser"

$site | Get-SPWeb -limit all | ForEach-Object {

    # Get all document libraries
    $lists = $_.Lists | where  {$_.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary"}

    # Loop libraries
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $lists.Count; $i++)
    { 
        try
        {
            # Get current view
            $view = $lists[$i].DefaultView

            if($view) 
            {
                # Delete if already exist
                while($view.ViewFields.ToStringCollection().Contains($column))
                {
                    $view.ViewFields.delete($column)

                    $view.Update()
                }

                # Add column
                if(!$view.ViewFields.ToStringCollection().Contains($column))
                {     
                    $view.ViewFields.add($column)

                    $view.Update()
                }
            }
        }
        catch [Exception]
        {
            write-output ("  Error: " + $_.Exception.ToString())
        }
    }
}

$site.Dispose()
```